# Storing Profesional Mathematical Equations into Mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

the equation should not look like √((x+a)^n=∑_(k=0)^n▒〖(n¦k) x^k a^(n-k) 〗)
but like [image: this is what they call professional kind of display mathematical equations]

Which coding and library for formulas I should use to get nice formula representations in PHP where the formulas can be stored in mysql?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML

Comment: what this to do with php, html and mysql?

Comment: What format is this, you can store BLOB and Text to mysql tables. Your question is not clear what are you trying to do? show us some code.

Comment: Am try to develop an application about storing questions and answers for mathematics and physics, the teacher will be allowed to record their questions and pick them for examination construction.

Comment: so what am stack is how clearly to store and view mathematical notation and equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is no question about storing (aside from storing images). it is question about how can you represent a formula/equitation in your database that can be converted afterwards in a nice representation.

the representation is done with any matching library in the language which you use to display the query results (PHP?).

or **are you asking which coding and library for formulas you should use to get nice formula representations in PHP where the formuas can be stored in mysql?**

Comment: Yes,  Am asking which coding and library for formulas you should use to get nice formula representations in PHP where the formuas can be stored in mysql?

Comment: then edit your question and explain your problem in detail. maybe some nice examples, what you have and what you want.